# Using active records to display data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

so I believe I have it right (im new to active records).
the problem I am having I keep getting error

```
Message: Call to a member function getbank() on a non-object
```

My code is simple

**Controller**

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $data = array();

        if($query = $this->profile_model->getbank())
        {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }

        $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
    }

}
```

**model**

```
   class Profile_model extends CI_Model {

    function getbank()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('bank');
    return $query->results();
}
```

Its so simple, I cant see a error, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

**Controller**

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $data = array();
        $this->load->model('profile_model'); # Added
        $query = $this->profile_model->getbank(); # Changed

        if(!empty($query)) # Changed
        {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }

        $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class Profile_model extends CI_Model {

    public function getbank()  # Changed
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('bank');
        return $query->result();  # Changed
    }
}
```

**Update**

Simple answer, thanks to all those who tried helping. I had the model file name with a small letter not a capital.

```
Eg profile_model.php

should be Profile_model.php
```

However, this solution is elegant and simple, so it improved my code so il accept this one.

Comment: hmm still getting a error, il keep trying this one, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It may be because you didn't load your model?
Try changing your controller to:

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $data = array();

        $this->load->model('Profile_model');

        if($query = $this->Profile_model->getbank())
        {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }

        $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
    }

}
```

Comment: when i try this I get 'File: /***/***public_html/***/***/application/controllers/Profile.php
Line: 15
Function: model'